# How should I prepare for a meeting with a client about large amount of bugs?

Tags: meetings, clients

I have a meeting tomorrow to discuss concerns about the many bugs inside of an application I recently upgraded.

How do I prepare for such a meeting?

Comment: Imagine you are the client.  What do you think they are going to want?

Comment: @Keltari, an explanation of why there are so many bugs.

Comment: @Daniel As a software developer, significant majority of users have zero comprehension of why bugs exist, and none of them will accept responsibility of contributing to the problem (What do you mean I can't keep 500 tabs opened in Chrome and play 15 YouTube videos at the same time? What do you mean the requirements are changed every week? I am the customer, I'm always right! etc., etc.)

Comment: How to prepare for a meeting about lots of bugs: _Bring a fly-squatter and a can of raid.._ ;)

Comment: Why are there a lot of bugs?

Comment: @Kilisi There are no such things as bugs - they are called 'unfinished features'..

Comment: @Kilisi, well I inherited the project with bugs due to code quality, the application was also due an upgrade. Some of the old bugs are gone, but there are some new bugs due to an upgrade, from RN 53.3 to RN 60.4, yeah there was going to be bugs, especially with so many third-party libs that are not maintained, one of the authors admitted to me he knew nothing about RNs autolinking and then proceeded not to update his documentation at all. Two other libs I submitted PRs so my customer and nobody else would have future problems, never merged, never reviewed.

Comment: was the purpose of the upgrade to fix the app? Sounds like you made it worse

Comment: @Kilisi, No I did not make it worse. Are you familiar with React Native at all? Their application was only going to get worse with time. Not sure if you are familiar with the recent changes where everyone had to get compliant with Androidx. It has deprecated lifecycle methods, logic inside of constructor functions that have no business being there. So an upgrade with an RN project that major, there was going to be bugs, on top of code quality and unmaintained third-party libs.

Comment: Way out of my field..... hope it works out for you

Comment: @Kilisi, yeah so React Native is fast evolving, breaking changes project. Just to use React Native is asking for bugs without the poor code quality and unmaintained third-party libs. I upgraded the project to 60.4 when it was brand new, that was a month ago maybe, RN is now on version 61.x. Newcomers ask me why did you only upgrade to 60 when its on...dude, when the upgrade was done, 60.4 was the newest version. I believe the hard conversation was never had by the original authors who charged big bucks. "I know you want this feature now, but it will cost you later" type of conversation.

Comment: @JoeStrazzere, yes.

Comment: @JoeStrazzere, sounds good. I was not planning to be defensive, more educational than anything. Like their team is always commenting in JIRA, that it works on React web, which sounds to me like they assume Reactjs and React Native are exactly the same, otherwise I am unclear the constant need to compare apples with oranges. I guess I will leave out the education on third-party libs, but my partner suggested otherwise. I guess we shall see. As far as what I am going to do, no problem explaining that, when, well I thought the estimate was for that, seems to me they just don't like the estimate.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try to front-foot the conversation and prepare:

- Identify a list of all bugs you're aware of
- Make a note of the status of each bug (i.e. Outstanding, work in progress, resolved etc)
- Identify which ones you feel are the most important
- Consider some recommendations to fix the bugs

If I was attending a meeting I would want to be well prepared and not caught like a deer in the headlights.  Good luck!

Comment: This is good stuff, but the most important thing is **make sure you are listening to the client**. If you treat it as a defensive exercise, in which you try to convince him that you are on top of everything and everything you are not on top of isn't important you risk missing the feedback on what the client thinks is important.

Comment: @DJClayworth What a great point, I absolutely agree.

Answer (score 5):

While doing your own prep in terms of issues and potential solutions is important, you should also prepare for the emotional element.

Often in this kind of meeting the client wants to be heard as much as anything else. Mentally prepare to let the affected parties vent without taking anything personally or becoming defensive.  Be ready to respond in the affirmative to the various points in a neutral way, with a words like 'understood', 'okay', 'uh-huh', 'I'll make a note of that', etc.

After they have expressed initial concerns, ask if there is anything else. Continue asking that question and responding calmly/neutrally until until they run out of things to say.

After that initial venting session, you should be able to move the discussion on to next steps in a productive way, focussing on prioritization and solutions for moving forward.

I find it helpful to remember (and sometimes mention) that from NASA to Microsoft to Apple, nobody is shipping bug free code. Bugs happen, this is normal, it's the next steps that matter.

Answer (score -1):

What you say is a bit unclear. If you installed a new version of your company’s software at a customer site, and the customer is unhappy with the many bugs in the new version, then the most important thing for you to do is that you agree with the right people at your company what you can say to make the customer happier than they are right now.